# DelayedConfirmationView doesn`t while changing layouts

Tags: wear-os

I am pretty new to programming and trying to build my first own app for my Android Wear.

Basically I want to see a new layout when pressing one of two buttons. On the new layout should be a `DelayedConfirmationView` with the possibility to cancel and to go back to the previous layout (kind of using "ok google" "Set timer to 5 seconds")

For this I created two layouts and coded in the manifest:

```
public void onClickcallSpringer(View view) {
  setContentView(R.layout.callspringer);
  DelayedConfirmationView DelayConfirmationView = (DelayedConfirmationView) findViewById(R.id.delayed_confirmation);
  DelayConfirmationView.setTotalTimeMs(2000);
  DelayConfirmationView.setListener((DelayedConfirmationView.DelayedConfirmationListener) this);
  DelayConfirmationView.start();
}
```

This leads to an crash, when pressing the button in my app.

I tried to understand the function `DelayedConfirmationView` from another App, but there it also leads to a crash (https://github.com/livefront/android-wear-demo).

I hope somebody can help me with this (and maybe explain to me how to solve this with a new activity as well).

Comment: Found my mistake: I had to make a new activity.

I am using now a .setOnClickListener to start a new Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake: I had to make a new activity.

I am using now a .setOnClickListener to start a new Activity

```
button_callspringer.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, callspringer.class));})
```

and in the new class I coded on the onCreate-Methode:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.callspringer);

    DelayedConfirmationView delayedconfirmationview_experte  =  (DelayedConfirmationView)      findViewById(R.id.delayed_confirmation_springer_view);

    delayedconfirmationview_experte.setTotalTimeMs(5000);
    delayedconfirmationview_experte.setListener(this);
    delayedconfirmationview_experte.start();}
```

This leads to the wished result. Maybe this will help someone one day too.